# CUDA 11.8 and Pytorch with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Ti Laptop GPU (Not working GPU as compute engine)

Tags: pip, pytorch, conda, torch

I'm trying to use my GPU as compute engine with Pytorch.

I have all the drivers (522.06) with CUDA 11.8 installed in my local machine, but Pytorch can't recognize my GPU.

I used different options for downloading, the last one:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Comment: DId you maybe try to install pytorch previously with a command without cuda, because I had a similar problem and I had to first uninstall all previous versions, because I accidentally had CPU version.
And only after installing it again, I got CUDA support.

Comment: I had the same issue and I uninstalled torch first and then I reran the above mentioned command. I am able to use GPU with torch then

Answer (score 1):

do you have nvidia based CPU? (as opposed to AMD based RADEON)?.
what OS are you running?

If you have nvidia based GPU, you need to install NVIDIA Driver first for your OS, and then install Nvidia CUDA toolkit. To confirm the driver installed correctly, run nvidia-smi command from your terminal. It should display the GPU you have in your system. If this command fails, try reinstalling again. I have also listed the steps below.

If you have secure boot enabled, it might cause the driver install to fail as well. Read below how to both enable secure boot and the driver installed without disabling secure boot.

Assuming you are running ubuntu run the following command

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

if the command fails, install the package first by running:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

The command will list what kind of nvidia cards you have, and the device drivers you need to install. Look for a line that ends with "recommended".

for example, this is what mine looks like:

```
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
driver   : nvidia-driver-525 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-525-open - distro non-free recommended
```

I tried to install the"nvidia-driver-525-open" driver but it wasn't working. I tried "nvidia-driver-525", and it works. so feel free to try both using

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-525 (modify the driver name with whatever you see from the output of the ubunt-drivers above)
```

if you have a UEFI enabled computer (i.e. secure boot enabled in BIOS), this installation will prompt you to specify a "password / key". After you are done installing, when you restart the computer, you will be prompted with 3 options. I dont remember what they are, but roughly the first one was "CONTINUE TO BOOT". The second one is "REGISTER WITH A KEY" or something like that. It is important that you do NOT continue to boot, pick the second option instead to register the driver you just installled, it will prompt you for a "password" you keyed in during the installation process.

Once you are done installing the driver, issue this command :

```
nvidia-smi
```

you should see your video card listed like below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.60.11    Driver Version: 525.60.11    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |

|======================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   36C    P8     5W /  N/A |      3MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

If you don't see the output above, try a different driver from the ubuntu-drivers command. I tried the open version and it didn't work.
If you are having problem getting the nvidia-smi command to run, this means you have not successfully installed the driver. One option that I would NOT recommend is to disable secure boot from your BIOS.

once you have the driver installed, proceed with installing the [Cuda toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-8-0-download-archive). I chose the runfile/local install type from the nvidia website. You can see the install guide from nvidia [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).

This installation will prompt you to install the driver again when you run it. Do NOT install the driver again if you have successfully install the driver above. I tried installing the driver from this runfile, but it wasn't working for me.

once installed, run the following command:

```
nvcc -V
```

it should tell you that the CUDA driver is installed and it will tell you the cuda version

Answer (score 0):

Following steps may help :-

1. deactivate the conda environment
2. remove the environment
3. create fresh environment
4. re-download the pytorch module
5. uninstall onlycpu from the given environment. onlycpu is some kind of package that hinders pytorch communication with gpu. (as the name suggests 'only cpu !!')
6. check for cuda is available.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other neat options, but to use Cuda with 3050 ti, Wikipedia gives Cuda version compatibility for a variety of GPU types in the link, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA. Compute capability for 3050 Ti, 3090 Ti etc., is 8.6, which corresponds to Cuda SDK version of 11.1 - 11.4.

I have created another environment alongside the (base), which was installed with Python 3.11. For conda with a downgraded Python version (<3.10), this installation code worked for me. You can copy and run it in the anaconda prompt.

```
conda install pytorch==1.12.1 torchvision==0.13.1 torchaudio==0.12.1 
cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch
```

p.s, You can check how to create and manage environments in conda as described in the link https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment.

Answer (score 0):

versions for cuda 11.8 at todays date

```
conda install pytorch==2.0.0 torchvision==0.15.0 torchaudio==2.0.0 pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```